# Restler Php : Vendor MIME Issue

Tags: php, versioning, restler

I am trying to figure out the API versioning using [Vendor MIME](http://restler3.luracast.com/examples/_012_vendor_mime/readme.html) in Restler 3.0.

Now the issue which I am facing is that I am not able figure out how to explicitly use the versions.
I used the [REST Console](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rest-console/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn?hl=en) at my local MAC machine.

I provided **Accept Content-Type Header** as **application/vnd.somevendor-v1+json** for version **1** and **application/vnd.somevendor-v2+json** for version **2** but the reponse which I get is always of the **version 1** script.

Comment: there seems to be a bug! we will fix and update you ASAP

Comment: ok sure thanks , i will be waiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have fixed it just now in v3 branch and it will soon be part of RC5

When we refactored restler to make it modular this functionality disappeared

Thanks for helping us find this issue

Comment: hi @Luracast , has this change been update at composer package ?